# How to manage BackPress in fragment more than 10+ time?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, onbackpressed

I want to manage backpress in fragment , i know to handle brackpress in activity by calling onBackpress method.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

But i implemented fragment in to the activity and its replace morethan 10+ times , so whenever i press back key apps close.

so i want to manage backpress in fragment with multiple time.

if anyone know best solution then please give your answer , i already tried many solution given by similar question but its not working.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can used This way handle backpress on Fragment

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (getView() != null) {
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                        if (Constants.getInstance().checkIsAudioPlay()) {
                            stopAudioPlaying();
                            refreshView();
                            btnPlayALL.setText(R.string.play_all);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's `onBackPressed()` method add the following:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fragmentManager.getFragments().size() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Also don't forget to override the `onPause()` method of your fragment and handle the tasks you want the fragment to finish when the back button is pressed.